# Download a file using OOS_UTIL_WEB that has been zipped

Tags: oracle, zip, oracle-apex

I've just started playing around with Oracle APEX, so please forgive me. I'm trying to download a set of files from the database, zip them, then have the user download them via a application.

I've heard that OOS_UTIL_WEB.DOWNLOAD_FILE can help with this, so I've installed it and can see the packages. If that isn't a good way, please shout, very new to this!

Below is the code I have, which selects the files I want to include, then zips them. Then, if I have got it right, would then prompt the download.

When I try to run the code on a button press, I get the error:

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0

Their documentation: https://github.com/OraOpenSource/oos-utils/blob/master/docs/oos_util_web.md#download_file

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong and haven't worked with APEX enough to known how to troubleshoot it.

I'm using Apex version 18.1.0 on a Oracle 12c DB.

```sql
DECLARE

    v_ZIP_FILE BLOB;

BEGIN

    FOR v_FILE IN ( SELECT  DATA_FILENAME,
                            DATA_CONTENT
                    FROM    MY_MONEY_WEEK_UPLOADS
                    WHERE   USER_ID = :P15_USER_ID )

    LOOP

        APEX_ZIP.ADD_FILE (
            P_ZIPPED_BLOB   => v_ZIP_FILE,
            P_FILE_NAME     => v_FILE.DATA_FILENAME,
            P_CONTENT       => v_FILE.DATA_CONTENT
        );

    END LOOP;

    APEX_ZIP.FINISH (
        P_ZIPPED_BLOB       => v_ZIP_FILE );

    OOS_UTIL_WEB.DOWNLOAD_FILE (
        P_FILENAME          => 'Download.zip',
        P_BLOB              => v_ZIP_FILE );

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please Go to the `specific page > Advanced > Reload on Submit` and change it to `Always`. Hope this will resolve the issue.

In APEX 5.1 or above, if Reload on Submit is set "Only for Success" (the default), it will use the new optimized page submission process, and expect a specifically formatted JSON result returned from the APEX engine.  Obviously, when you employ a page process which overrides the HTP buffer and emit binary content (instead of a well-formed JSON result), the libraries on the page don't know how to deal with that, and thus, results in this obtuse "Unexpected token r..." message. [For Reference - https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/12/errors-when-downloading-file-on-page.html?_sm_au_=isV6WJ02r1MnWkP5]

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Is there a better way of doing this in that case then?

Comment: This method is fine. I have enabled `Always` and it works fine.